# imagettftext() doesn't work in wordpress even with the font in the same directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have downloaded the font from my sites uploads and placed it in the SAME directory (I checked with sftp).

I also have tried referencing the exact file location when placed somewhere else using the same file directory I used to save it there. Neither work.

Still my generated image is just a black rectangle.

Help

NOTE: imagestring() works just fine.
NOTE2: when I var_dumped imagettftext() it returns bool(false)

```
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');

function generate_image_test() {
    
    $image = imagecreate(500, 90);
    
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
    $grey_shade = imagecolorallocate($image,40,40,40);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

    // Local font files, relative to script
    $font = file_get_contents("https://wodwodwod.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/RedHatDisplay-Bold.ttf");
    chmod(file_put_contents("/srv/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/font.ttf", $font), 0755);
    echo file_put_contents("/srv/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/font.ttf", $font);

    
    $myfont = './font.ttf'; // I've done a million variations of this: font | /font.ttf  | /font etc...
    
    imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 0, 0, $white, $myfont, "test");
    //imagestring($image, 5, 5, 20, 'test imgstring!', $white);
    
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($image); //, NULL, 100);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $i = ob_get_clean();
    
    //var_dump(gd_info());
    
    return "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $i )."' id=\"instagram_challenge\">";
}

add_shortcode('image_test', 'generate_image_test');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates given by x and y will define the basepoint of the first character (roughly the lower-left corner of the character).

Meaning if it's 0,0 the text will be above the image.

```
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 20, 20, $white, "/srv/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/font.ttf", 'test');
```

Move it down a bit and it's visible.